# Learning Prolog, Sudoku Solver

Tags: prolog, sudoku, constraint-satisfaction

my problem is:
While learning Prolog i wanted to make a NxN Sudoku solver.
This solver will get the input like

```
    [[1,2,3,4],[3,4,1,2],[2,3,4,1],[4,1,2,3]]
```

Where some of them might be variables. The solver has to solve that Sudoku.
The problem is way smaller:

```
    firstElementsOf([],_).
    firstElementsOf([[X|_]|Rest2],Y) :-
      firstElementsOf(Rest2,Y2),
      append([X],[Y2],NotFlat),
      flatten(NotFlat,Y).
```

This should be the beginning of checking, if every column has distinct numbers. The `Y` from `firstElementsOf` should contain only the first elements of the given rows. In the Example:

```
    [1,3,2,4]
```

Sadly, thanks to append, it always adds another empty space to the `Y` list.
It gives:

```
    [1,3,2,4,_1320]
```

Question1: Is there a way to get rid of that `_1320`?

Question2: Is this even right? Will there be a way to get the 2nd and 3rd elements of the Input with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1: I suppose the error is in

```
firstElementsOf([],_).
```

I think should be

```
firstElementsOf([],[]).
```

Off topic: are you sure that you can't simply write the other clause as follows?

```
firstElementsOf([[X|_]|Rest2],[X|Y]) :-
  firstElementsOf(Rest2,Y).
```

For question 2: I propose a more general predicate: the following `getPosList/3` with support of `getPosElem/3`

```
getPosElem([H | _], 1, H).

getPosElem([_ | T], Pos, H) :-
  Pos > 1,
  Pm1 is Pos - 1,
  getPosElem(T, Pm1, H).

getPosList([], _, []).

getPosList([H | T], Pos, [E | L]) :-
  getPosElem(H, Pos, E),
  getPosList(T, Pos, L).
```

It extract a list of all elements in position `Pos`, so

```
getPosList([[1,2,3,4],[3,4,1,2],[2,3,4,1],[4,1,2,3]], 1, L),
```

it's equivalent to `firstElementOf([[1,2,3,4],[3,4,1,2],[2,3,4,1],[4,1,2,3]], L)` and extract `[1, 3, 2, 4]`,

```
getPosList([[1,2,3,4],[3,4,1,2],[2,3,4,1],[4,1,2,3]], 2, L),
```

extract `[2, 4, 3, 1]`,

```
getPosList([[1,2,3,4],[3,4,1,2],[2,3,4,1],[4,1,2,3]], 3, L),
```

extract `[3, 1, 4, 2]`,

```
getPosList([[1,2,3,4],[3,4,1,2],[2,3,4,1],[4,1,2,3]], 4, L),
```

extract `[4, 2, 1, 3]` and

```
getPosList([[1,2,3,4],[3,4,1,2],[2,3,4,1],[4,1,2,3]], 5, L),
```

or a number greather than 5, return false

Comment: For the first... it trully works... i don't even understand why.

Comment: For the second... i can do that too... but i also don't get it :) Let me look at it later:)

Comment: @Shuumi ; answer improved (with a point (2) proposal; for the "why" in point (1), take in count that `[]` is "empty list" and `_` is "a value"; if you write `firstElementsOf([],_)` you impose the extraction of "a value" (so an unbounded variable, `_1320` in your example) from the empty list

Comment: That is wonderful! Of course i will try to understand every little bit of the text you have wrote, but at the first glance i see, that your work is exacly what i need, to finish that solver. Thank you very much!

Comment: @shuumi - a little of topic: sudoku is a tipical constraint satisfaction problem; in some prolog environments (gprolog and swi-prolog, by example) it's available a CLP library; I suggest to search and give a look at it.